# Azure virtual network for WebSite and VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a VM hosted in an azure and i use "**Manage Acl**" to filter the IP addresses that are allowed for access.

I need to allow a website hosted in the same azure account, and the same location (West Europe) to acces the VM.

I created a **Virtual network**, added the dns for the VM and the Website, which gives the VM this IP `10.0.0.5` and the Website this one `10.0.0.4` in the subnet `10.0.0.0/11`.

Back to "**Manage Acl**" i gave access to the subnet **and** to the website like this :

[image]

**The problem:** The Website still can't access the VM ! am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: The ACL's are for your endpoints (public facing). If your VM's and Websites are already in the same Virtual Network there should be no need to setup ACL's. But you can remove your endpoints as the communication will be on the Virtual Network and not using public endpoints.

Comment: @miracledev thats exactly where i want to get, communication in the same virtual network while having ACL as I want to protect the IP/port.

Comment: Thats not possible: "Currently, you can specify network ACLs for endpoints only. You can’t specify an ACL for a virtual network or a specific subnet contained in a virtual network. " from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn376541.aspx

And i honestly don't know why you would want that, the machine is ONLY accesible from other machines in the VNET if you have no endpoints defined so its already "secured" from outsiders

Comment: Ok, now i removed the endpoint from the ACL definition. the VM is still blocking the traffic coming from the website.

Comment: Is the VM connected to the Virtual Network and the website too?

Comment: Thats a good question. i just setup the virtual network for the dns of the VM and the Website, i dont know if i need to do an extra configuration to get this working.

Comment: restarting the vm and the website doesnt seem to work.

Comment: The VM needs to be added to a Virtual Network on creation and using "Create From Gallery" option, you cant add it to a virtual network later.

Comment: I managed to added it, by deleting and keeping the attached disk. then i created a new vm from the gallery with the old attached disk. i also added the website to the vnet in the preview portal. but nothing seems to satisfy azure !!!

Comment: How are you testing the connection? What error do you get?

Comment: I dont know why it is that hard to get two instances of the same azure account, in the same datacenter communicating with each other.

Comment: Long story short, the endpoint i need to secure is for "elasticsearch" (since i was hacked from its port and i dont want this to happen again) . if no endpoint is specified in the ACL => no communication. if the endpoint is specified => communication is allowed. at the moment i add a rule (example allowing my ip address) => no more communication.

Answer (score 0):

If the VM is still blocking the traffic from the website, it is possible that either your VM firewall is on the way or you are accessing the VM using its Public IP Address. If you want to achieve ACLs in the Virtual Network, the better feature to use is [Network Security Groups](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/).